# PHPMailer keeps spinning without giving an error

Tags: php, error-handling, phpmailer

I'm trying to implement PHPMailer in my contact form, but for some reason I can't manage to do it. When I submit my form it keeps "spinning" and after a while just returns my php script in the url without any output of errors etc. Error reporting is enabled. I don't have any idea what it could be.

The problem should be somewhere in this function. If you need more information, please ask me.

```
function sendMail($naam, $email, $phone, $subj, $msg, $chkArr) {
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $TO = ' ... '; //TODO

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        $mail->setLanguage('nl');
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; //TODO
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = ' ... '; //TODO
        $mail->Password = ' ... '; //TODO
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->setFrom($email, $naam);
        $mail->addAddress($TO, 'Animagie');
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->Subject = 'Animagie: ' . $subj;
        $mail->Body = createHTMLMessage($naam, $email, $phone, $msg, $chkArr);
        $mail->AltBody = createNonHTMLMessage($naam, $email, $phone, $msg, $chkArr);

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $error = "Bericht kon niet worden verstuurd: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            echo $error;
            var_dump($mail);
            exit;
        } else {
            //TODO: return to success page
            echo 'Bericht succesvol verstuurd!';
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: What calls this function? The spinning sounds like it is the browser just waiting for the PHP to complete but it times out (maybe max execution time). What is the status code of the page when it finishes?

Comment: There is an example for Gmail at PHPMailer's github that you should checkout, because they show how to enable verbose output which will help you tracking what's happening. I found it here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Comment: Here is the 'full' script (stripped down the validation part) https://pastebin.com/hCr7uT8L The return status is 503. (I should've put that in my question, my bad.)

Comment: @sidyll I don't know how I could miss that part .. I've looked in the repository before, but I never found the part where the SMTPDebug & debug output could be enabled. However even with those two set, still the same result: nothing.

Comment: If your ISP blocks outbound SMTP, you'll usually have to wait for timeouts before getting any kind of response. Set `SMTPDebug = 3` To get more feedback on what it's waiting for. Troubleshooting guide has tests you can do to find out what's wrong.

Comment: @JC97 No problem. 503? Please check your server logs.

Comment: Okay, I've started thinking on what @Synchro said with the SMTP may be blocked. It was indeed blocked. I now use the ISP's own SMTP server, and suddenly I get errormessages. Thanks everyone.